# SQLSMS Intellisense on linked server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms, linked-server

I'm trying to work Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 10.0.5538.0 (latest right now) with Intellisense on linked servers, for example:

```
SELECT Column FROM [LinkedServer].DatabaseName.dbo.Table WITH(NOLOCK)
```

But I couldn't find a way to make intellisense show results as I write SQL code (it works fine with non-linked servers)

Things I've tried:

- Look for answers in SQLSMS docs.
- Look for specific config option in the application.
- Update local cache in Edit -> IntelliSense -> Refresh local cache.

Thanks for your help,

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Apparently this isn't supported.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/ef973d28-6450-451c-840f-9d14c7ae4ed1/intellisense-invalid-object-name-on-linked-database-runs-fine?forum=sqldatabaseengine

One reason given is that this linked server could be Oracle, Excel... anything, and to support that is unfeasible

Comment: Shame that they wouldn't even try to check if it's an SQL Server and if we have permissions to get the metadata from that server. I mean, I'm often connected to the linked server in the same SSMS session! Alternatively, stop showing the squigly lines for linked server objects.

Answer (score 2):

As an addendum to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52105625/3744182) by [BenXvisual](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6826933/benxvisual), in SSMS 17.9.1 (14.0.17289.0) hotkey for switching off Intellisense is **Ctrl-B, Ctrl-I**.

Comment: ssurba, instead of posting an answer which merely links to another answer, please instead [flag the question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

While it isn't supported from a linked server at least turning off IntelliSense makes it a lot clearer. This can be done by simply pressing **CTRL-I** while in the query window. The same keyboard shortcut turns it back on again when required.

Comment: @ssurba writes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54408717/3744182) that *I just wanted to reply to previous comment that in SSMS 17.9.1 (14.0.17289.0) hotkey for switching off Intellisense is **Ctrl-B, Ctrl-I.***